# Autofac None of the constructors found

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection, autofac

I create a project WindowsForm Application with DependencyInjection using Autofac. I have a problem when I build it. This is my Program.cs

```
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerDependency();
        builder.RegisterType<DITestDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerDependency();
        // Repositories
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ProductCategoryRepository).Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();

        // Services
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ProductCategoryService).Assembly)
           .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
           .AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerDependency();
        Autofac.IContainer container = builder.Build();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(container.Resolve<Form1>());
```

I meet a error message

> DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ProductCategoryService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DITest.Service.IProductCategoryService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope

And

> DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = UnitOfWork (ReflectionActivator), Services = [DITest.Data.Infrastructure.IUnitOfWork], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope

And

> NoConstructorsFoundException: No accessible constructors were found for the type 'DITest.Data.Infrastructure.UnitOfWork'.

Anyone know how to fix this. Thanks you!!

Comment: Look at `UnitOfWork` -> does it have a public constructor?

Comment: Do you have a constructor which is parameterless and public? You have not posted your code for those classes. Also, it is thé same error so fix one and all will be fixed. Just try one of them at a time.

Comment: Thanks. But constructor and paramatter were public

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UnitOfWork` probably doesn't have a public constructor, but you didn't post the code for it.

Comment: My UnitOfWork class had a public constructor.

Comment: Don't downvote people who try to help you when you didn't even post your code. Your error message says "No accessible constructors were found for the type 'DITest.Data.Infrastructure.UnitOfWork'." That means no public constructor, so without posting your code, nobody will be able to give you any better answer.